# React js installing a npm module peer dependency issue

Tags: reactjs, npm

Trying to install the [react js pagination](https://github.com/vayser/react-js-pagination) component but I get this warning about peer dependency.

[image]

Not sure how to solve this.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A peer dependency means that you need to have the dependency installed in your project alongside the package that requires the peer dependency.

In your case, you can fix the problem by simply installing *html-webpack-plugin*:

```
npm install --save-dev html-webpack-plugin
```

→ see [article explaining in detail](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/)

Comment: The `"html-webpack-plugin": "2.21.0"` is already installed in the `devDependencies`. I'm so confused!

Comment: I don't think the culprit is react-js-pagination, that doesn't have any dependency to html-webpack-plugin at all. Can you include more of the npm console output?